# How do I get .click to smooth scroll for an anchor when a theme smooth scroll already exists

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I have jQuery for 3 column id's to make them clickable that navigate to anchor id's further down the page.

If I add CSS smooth scroll

```
`Html{scroll-behavior:smooth}`
```

it breaks my theme's smooth scroll which I need for other parts of the site and I've tried a bunch of othe examples such as: 
    
    `<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 5000);
    return false;
        });
        });
    </script>`
in JS but I can't get those to work. 
This is what I use to make the columns clickable:

```
    jQuery('#heures, #services, #con').css('cursor','pointer');
jQuery('#heures').click(function() {window.location="#nos-heures";});
jQuery('#services').click(function() {window.location="#nos-services";});
jQuery('#con').click(function() {window.location="#contact";});
```

The clickable part works as intended, but I have not been able to include smooth scroll

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Vanilla JS using Elelment.scrollIntoView. Keep in mind that smooth scrolling is not available in IE, but it will jump them there.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Nice one @Leathel!